# How to put AuthenticationFilter in front of my third-party servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cxf

I want to integrate Spring Security and Apache CXF SOAP web services. Now I'm trying to understand how to put a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` or `DigestAuthenticationFilter` in front of my CXF Servlet?

That's how I initialize the app:

```
public class WebServiceDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, WebServiceConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.setParent(rootContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic cxfDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("CXF dispatcher", CXFServlet.class);
        cxfDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        cxfDispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
    }
}
```